# How configure JMSSerializer in Symfony to serialize custom class to/from int?

Tags: symfony, jms-serializer

I am working on a Symfony 3.4 based web app project which uses `JMSSerializer` to serialize different custom classes to JSON to send this data to mobile apps.

**How can I serialize/deserialize a custom class to/from to int?**

---

Assume we have the following classes:

```
<?php

// AppBundle/Entity/...

class NotificationInfo {
    public $date;      // DateTime
    public $priority;  // Int 1-10
    public $repeates;  // Boolean

    public function toInt() {
        // Create a simple Int value
        //  date = 04/27/2020
        //  priority = 5
        //  repeats = true
        //  ==> int value = 4272020 5 1 = 427202051
    }

    public function __construnct($intValue) {
       // ==> Split int value into date, priority and repeats...
    }
}


class ToDoItem {
    public $title;
    public $tags;
    public $notificationInfo;
}


// AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entiy.ToDoItem.yml
AppBundle\Entity\ToDoItem:
exclusion_policy: ALL
properties:
    title:
        type: string
        expose: true
    tags:
        type: string
        expose: true
    notificationInfo:
        type: integer
        expose: true
```

So the class `NotificationInfo` also has function to create it from int and to serialize it to in. How to tell the serializer that it should serialize the value of `$notificationInfo` to int?

I could use the following instead:

```
    notificationInfo:
        type: AppBundle\Entity\NotificationInfo
        expose: true
```

However in this case I need to configure the serialization of `NotificationInfo` where I can only specify which property should serialized to which value...

---

**EDIT:**

This is the JSON I would like to create:

```
{
    "title": "Something ToDO",
    "tags": "some,tags",
    "notificationInfo": 427202051
}
```

This is what I am NOT looking for:

```
{
    "title": "Something ToDO",
    "tags": "some,tags",
    "notificationInfo": {
        "intValue": 427202051
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried VirtualProperty() method of JMS serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot more digging I found the following solution for my problem: I added a custom serialization `Handler` which tells `JMSSerializer` how to handle my custom class:

```
class NotificationInfoHandler implements SubscribingHandlerInterface {

    public static function getSubscribingMethods() {
        return [
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_SERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => 'NotificationInfo',
                'method' => 'serializeNotificationInfoToJson',
            ],
            [
                'direction' => GraphNavigator::DIRECTION_DESERIALIZATION,
                'format' => 'json',
                'type' => 'NotificationInfo',
                'method' => 'deserializeNotificationInfoToJson',
            ],
        ;


    public function serializeNotificationInfoToJson(JsonSerializationVisitor $visitor, NotificationInfo $info, array $type, Context $context) {
        return $info->toInt();
    }

    public function deserializeNotificationInfoToJson(JsonDeserializationVisitor $visitor, $infoAsInt, array $type, Context $context) {
        return (is_int($infoAsInt) ? NotificationInfo::fromInt($infoAsInt) : NotificationInfo::emptyInfo());
    }

}
```

Thanks to `autowire` the handler is automatically added and can be used in the serializer metadata:

```
notificationInfo:
    type: NotificationInfo
    expose: true
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use `VirtualProperty` method to add any method of you class
>   into json response

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

class NotificationInfo 
{
    /**
     * @return int
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("formatedLocation")
     */
    public function toInt()
    {
        return 4272020;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding a virtual property to `NotificationInfo` would only change the content of serialized object. But I am looking to serialize the complete `NotificationInfo` object/property into one int. I have edited the question to to demonstrate the difference.